# Make Sherman-Morrison update more efficient

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, linear-algebra, gradient

I need to compute the covariance matrix of the parameter gradients taken on the points of a subset of the CIFAR10 dataset. For that I have this code:

```
from torch.func import functional_call, vmap, grad

model1 = LogisticModel().to(device)

def loss_fn(predictions, targets):
  loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
  return loss(predictions, targets)

def compute_loss(params, buffers, sample, target):
  batch = sample.unsqueeze(0)
  targets = target.unsqueeze(0)

  predictions = functional_call(model1, (params, buffers), (batch,))
  loss = loss_fn(predictions, targets)
  return loss

ft_compute_grad = grad(compute_loss)
ft_compute_sample_grad = vmap(ft_compute_grad, in_dims=(None, None, 0, 0))

def sherman_morrison_update(A, u, v):
  vT = v.T
  Au = A @ u

  alpha = 1/(1 + vT@Au)
  A = A - alpha*torch.outer(Au, vT@A)
  return A

testloader1 = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size = 512)
params = {k: v.detach() for k, v in model1.named_parameters()}
buffers = {k: v.detach() for k, v in model1.named_buffers()}
w = 0

p_covs = {p:torch.eye(q.flatten().shape[0]).to(device) for p,q in param_grads.items()}
param_grad_mean = {p:torch.zeros(q.flatten().shape[0]).to(device) for p,q in param_grads.items()}

for x,y in tqdm(testloader1):
  param_grads = ft_compute_sample_grad(params, buffers, x.to(device), y.to(device))
  for p,q, mean in zip(param_grads.values(), p_covs, param_grad_mean):
    for p_grad in p:
      w += 1
      diff = p_grad.flatten() - param_grad_mean[mean]
      param_grad_mean[mean] += diff / w
      p_covs[q] = sherman_morrison_update(A=p_covs[q], u=diff, v= diff)
```

Now, this is very inefficient and doing this in every iteration is quite time taking.
Also, we can't really take the gradients of the parameters at all points at once because that causes memory issues (thus I shifted to Sherman-Morrison).

Is there a way to make it more efficient? A better implementation of Sherman-Morrison? Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), you are not calculating the covariance of the gradient vectors, but it's inverse. If that is the goal, I think it is much more efficient just to calculate the covariance matrix first (just sum up the outer products), and then take its inverse at the end.

Side note, that as `u == v == diff` and `A` is a symmetric matrix for your call to `sherman_morrison_update`, so `vT@A == Au.T`. This can save you some computation, although not as much as just taking the inverse at the end at once.